# Convert from pcap to csv

Tags: csv, tcp, wireshark, packet, pcap

I need to convert a file from PCAP format to CSV format.
Furthermore, I also need to select only some packets (e.g. only the tcp or only the modbus) to export in CSV. Any solutions? Thx!

Comment: Take a look at tshark with output fields for the fields you care about. (-T fields -e `field_name`). You can specify the delimiter as well so that it can be a valid csv.

Comment: Daniel it depends a lot on what information you want in the CSV. It probably doesn't make sense to see raw packet content in there. Take a look at [Zeek](https://zeek.org) — it parses lots of protocols to turn them into meaningful logs, tab-separated or in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark can output dissected packets as .csv file.

1. Open .pcap file with Wireshark.
2. Filter packets you want to export.
3. Go to File->Packet Dissections->As CSV ...
4. Select Displayed in Packet Range if you want to export only filtered packets.
5. Save your file.

You can do it with tshark as well if you prefer console. See @RossJacobs comment

Comment: I have over half a million pcap files I need to convert to csv files. This won't work for me

Comment: @LostCrotchet try tshark with -T option